# Why is nameList.add not synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is a short bit of text from the Oracle Java Tutorials:

“Synchronized Statements

Another way to create synchronized code is with synchronized statements. Unlike synchronized methods, synchronized statements must specify the object that provides the intrinsic lock:

```
public void addName(String name) {
    synchronized(this) {
        lastName = name;
        nameCount++;
    }
    nameList.add(name);
}
```

In this example, the addName method needs to synchronize changes to lastName and nameCount, but also needs to avoid synchronizing invocations of other objects' methods. (Invoking other objects' methods from synchronized code can create problems that are described in the section on Liveness.) Without synchronized statements, there would have to be a separate, unsynchronized method for the sole purpose of invoking nameList.add.”

I understand their point about the flexibility Synchronized gives.  But why did Oracle decide that nameList.add did not need to be synchronized?  More generally, how can I determine which objects methods need to be synchronized and which don't?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing has its price, performance wise. The general rule of thumb (which the JDK itself also follows, in this case too) is not to synchronize unless it's absolutely required.

Since there are many, many cases where you'd want to add an element to a list without requiring synchronization (e.g., if said list is a local variable), it was not defined as synchronized. When you need to synchronize such an operation, you can always use a [`CopyOnWWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), or synchronize your access explicitly.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question (the same way I did upon a first glance). This isn't asking why `ArrayList` and other collections are not synchronized. Rather it is asking why, in the code example, the line `nameList.add()` is not included in the `synchronized` block.

Comment: C-A is correct.  It seems to me that unless nameList is thread safe, the code would not be safe.   I think if nameList is not thread safe, it must be in the synchronized block.  Am I correct?  Also, how could nameList be a local variable?  It's clearly not a local variable in addName.  If it were a local variable in any other method, it would not be in scope.  What other cases are there where you would want to add an element to a list without requiring synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

**Synchronize based on what you know the threads will access**.

- If they are trying to access a list then synchronize the getter. In this case, Oracle was synchronizing the call to the method ONLY.
- If they are trying to modify the list, then synchronize the reference to the list inside your block!

So:

```
synchronized(this.nameList){
 //now I'm safe to modify
  nameList.add(name);
 }
```

Comment: Even if other threads cannot access or modify the list, won't the above code cause memory consistency errors if nameList is not a thread safe collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thread safe ArrayList of Strings like this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

**the methods add() and remove() are thread safe.** If you don't need to iterate over the elements you're just fine.

**Note:** It is imperative that you manually synchronize on the returned collection when iterating over it

```
synchronized (list) {
  Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in the synchronized block
  while (list.hasNext())
     yourmethod(list.next()); // Your logic on elements...
}
```

Before using read the docs here: [Synchronized Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection(java.util.Collection))

Comment: I see that nameList might have been thread safe.  But if it had been an ArrayList it would not have been thread safe.  If it had been declared as an ArrayList, would the code be safe?  I'm not sure but I don't think so.  Wouldn't there be the possibility of memory consistency errors if nameList was an ArrayList, even if nameList wasn't accessable?

Comment: @ClarkS the way to declare a thread safe ArrayList is the one I show you above in line 1. If you declare it simply as ArrayList<String> list=new new ArrayList<String>(); then the thread safety is not guaranteed. Just declare it using the Collections.synchronizedList as above and you are safe to add.